# mysqlでDECLAREが使えない

Tags: mysql

以下のsqlだとsyntax errorになっていまいます。どう修正すればよいでしょうか？

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample()                                                                                                    

BEGIN                                                                                                    
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 2;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql コマンドは `;` をクエリの区切りと認識し、そこまでの文字列をサーバーに送信してしまいます。

まず delimiter でクエリの区切り文字を別の文字に変更してから CREATE PROCEDURE を行えばよいと思います。

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE sample()
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 2;
    -> END
    -> //
mysql> delimiter ;
```

マニュアルにも記述があります。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/create-procedure.html

Comment: delimiterを記述すると解決しました。
ありがとうございました。